# How to know whether PartialView is loaded by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My goal is very simple - I would like to add an image in the next empty div.
For example, I  have three divs. If the first div is not empty, I would like to add an image to the second div.

So, I have a very simple view:

```
<div id="imageDivF"></>
<div id="imageDivSecond"></>
<div id="imageDivT"></>
```

A very simple partial view:

```
<img id="hello"/>
```

AJAX code which loads partial view into div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        datatype:'json',
        url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
        autoupload: true,
        done: function (e, data) {
   if ($("#imageDivF").has("img").length==0) 
{ $('#imageDivF').load('/Home/ImagePartialView', { address: data.result.name });
// in this next row I would like to check whether #imageDivF contains image
//I should check whether #imageDivF contains image to decide whether it is necessary to put image to the next empty div
//pseudo code: if(#imageDivF) does not contain image, then image should be inserted to the next div #imageDivSecond
    }
```

How to check whether '#imageDivF' contains partial view(image inside)?
What I've tried:

```
$('#imageDivF').find('#hello');//not detected
 $(''hello", "'#imageDivF")// not detected
 $('#imageDivF #hello')// not detected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a callback function in `.load(url, data, cb)` method:

```
$('#imageDivF').load('/Home/ImagePartialView', { address: data.result.name }, function(){
    alert($(this).find('img').length !== 0); // true if image is there.
});
```

You have to check that in the callback function because `.load()` has the `async` nature  process, so it doesn't hold the code execution. whenever `.load()` method executes next line will also be executed because it does not wait for `.load()` to be finished.

That is why a callback function is there, you can put your code execution in it.

Comment: I need 'if' statement. Cause I should check whether #imageDivF contains image to decide whether it is necessary to put image to the next empty div:
    //pseudo code: if(#imageDivF) does not contain image, then image should be inserted to the next div #imageDivSecond. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Is my coding way correct of checking whether first div has an image?

Comment: @StepUp absolutely you can have a check in if condition and you can have a check for that particular element if the div is empty then call the `.load()` method.

Comment: How to implement it!? Please, see my updated code in question

Comment: I cannot figure out how to use 'if' operator and callback method.